URXVT tab feature cuts off bottom of terminal
In Ubuntu Focal with X server, I am using URXVT and I have enabled the tabs feature
  URxvt.perl-ext: tabbedalt             
  URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,tabbed 

However, it cuts off the bottom of the terminal. I have tried adjusting the URxvt.internalBorder but it does not help.
Anyone know how to fix, please?

